# How do be notified when a ViewController is removed from a NavigationController

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to be notified when a ViewController is removed from a UINavigationController because the back button was pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conjunction with eman's method, check

```
[navController.viewcontrollers count]
```

If it is one greater than before (you need to maintain a count) then something was pushed. If it is one less, and `viewWillDisappear:` was called, then the view controller was removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `viewWillDisappear:` in the view controller that is disappearing.  If the other view controller needs to be notified, you can use a delegate method to notify it:

```
//in the disappearing view controller, class MYViewController
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //do stuff you need to do
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myViewControllerDidDisappear:)]) 
        [self.delegate myViewControllerDidDisappear:self];  //bottom view controller is delegate
}
```

Comment: viewWillDisappear: also gets called if you push another view controller on top of it, not just when going back.